How To Add Custom Data While cerebo.add(data) Adding Data Toward Ttrategy?
I'm facing some of the problem about adding custom data for strategy.
Most of the case which I can search on Internet is the data contain OHLCV (which is the default by backtrader)
But now my custom data in the csv is composed of [Open, Close, High, Low, Volume, Increase Ratio, TurnOver Ratio]
When I run cerebo.add(data), It would run out of 'Lines_LineSeries_DataSeries_OHLC_OHLCDateTime_Abst'
How can I add the rest of the data toward my strategy, I knew it could use some of the data feed extend to custom your own data input, but it's now working in my case.

I copy the legacy source code and re-build a class re-do everything, maybe due to the version of python and package make this happen, check out the corresponding version prevent from this issue.
